# Tracking piwik installation

Tags: tracking, matomo

I am trying to track piwik installation itself not the piwik campaigns but so far I haven't had any luck.

Here are list of few things I did:

- In the config.ini.php, I have added following lines: [Debug] 
  track_visits_inside_piwik_ui = 999

  where 999 is the site id of the site I want to track.

  It does not generate any error and does not track anything.
- I modified piwik/plugins/CoreHome/templates/piwik_tag.tpl:
   {if $piwikUrl == 'http://demo.piwik.org/' || $debugTrackVisitsInsidePiwikUI || 'http://yourDomain/piwik/'}
  and changed var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker("piwik.php", 2);

  This also does not throw an error but does not track as well.

I have tried to put the piwik tracking code in the individual pages but there are no html codes where I can add them.

Any help will be very much Appreciated.
Anjali.

Answer (score 2):

Using internal tracking you can only track visits to idSite = 1. The setting you are using is invalid since `track_visits_inside_piwik_ui` is a boolean flag and can only accept values 0 and 1.

```
[Debug]
track_visits_inside_piwik_ui = 1
```

This is the only valid setting. Note that this is a debugging/development feature and should not be used in production.